# How can i use the hovering effect on the DIV in top of my css transform in Chrome? (in FF it works)

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

I am trying to make a grid of hexagons. For a funky effect I make use of the css transform effects. In FireFox this seems to function correct, but in Google Chrome the top div doesn't seem to give the expected hover effect. Here is the code I use:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    margin:0;
}
.board{
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(700px) rotateX(65deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(700px) rotateX(65deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(700px) rotateX(65deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(700px) rotateX(65deg);
    transform: perspective(700px) rotateX(65deg);
    padding:10;
}
.hex-row {
    clear: left;
}
.hex-row.even {
    margin-left: 53px;
}
.hex:hover{
    background: #446;
}
.hex:hover:before{
    border-bottom: 30px solid #446;
}
.hex:hover:after{
    border-top: 30px solid #446;
}

.hex:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 0; height: 0;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
}
.hex {
    width: 104px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #6C6;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.hex:after {
    content: " ";
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    border-top: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}
.hex.disabled{
    background-color: #888;
}
.hex.disabled:before {
    border-bottom: 30px solid #888;
}
.hex.disabled:after {
    border-top: 30px solid #888;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="board">
<div class="hex-row">
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
</div>
<div class="hex-row even">
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
</div>
<div class="hex-row">
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
</div>
<div class="hex-row even">
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
</div>
<div class="hex-row">
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
<div class="hex disabled"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For trying this out quickly you could use the following link: http://jsfiddle.net/a55eF/2/ and click the Run button. You will see the result in the right bottom.

Does anybody have suggestions on fixing the hovering?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body is preventing the hover event, that is the difference i see between firefox and google chrome. When you add height: 0px; to the body element it does trigger the hover event correctly.

Comment: Your answer works even better Black Soldier B, sorry Sean I will set this as the accepted answer, but I will use your angle-values.

Comment: I tried 0 and it caused the hover effect even when I was above the actual hex element.

Comment: That is not caused by the 0, the hover effect bug also appears in the first version. I think it is caused by the margin of the hex elements.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `height` to 10px and the rotations to 75deg:

http://jsfiddle.net/a55eF/5/

Seems as if you want to mess around with those parameters, specifically the height, to get the desired effect. It seems as if the lower the height was, the more of the top row you're able to hover over.

Comment: Thank you, I am satisfied with those values! Hopefully this works for Safari aswell. IE is not needed since i use this code for a platform which uses WebGL.